# Cannot call the REST with usual relative urls of new spring boot project

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I have two projects 
1. Project-UI (containing angular pages)
2. Project-REST (Rest web services)

Initially they used to be on same tomcat so I could call any of the REST resource with url "/Project-REST/Customer/id/1234" since the context path was same e.g. localhost:8080

Now, the Project-REST has been converted to Spring boot and uses inbuilt tomcat of the boot on a port say 8085. so my relative urls dont work.

is there any way to make it work so that I need not change all my urls.....    without entering context path ?

I am using eclipse as IDE

Comment: best and easy way is to make the context path (or base url) configurable in Project-UI

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 suggestions in random order:

1. All requests go to tomcat (*Project-UI*, port 8080), where you configure URL rewriting to redirect some requests to spring-boot (*Project-REST* port 8085). A quick google search produced [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html) and [this](https://github.com/paultuckey/urlrewritefilter/), both similar to `mod_rewrite` of Apache.
2. If as I understand &Project-UI* one contains static files, you can easily serve these from your spring-boot application at port 8085. Spring boot docs for serving static content [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content). In summary spring-boot will serve static content from a directory called `/static` (or `/public` or `/resources` or `/META-INF/resources`) in the classpath or from the root of the `ServletContext`.
3. Put a proxy server in front of both *Project-UI* and *Project-REST* and configure request redirects there. This is a more involved solution but may help you if you more projects in the future.